# SQL Server 2012 SSIS : retrieve line number in Flat File Connection Manager

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I'm developing a ETL, that uses a FFCM to parse data from a csv and loads it in a SQL Server table.

Some float data aren't parsing properly, so I need to see the result in the table and get back to the flat file to see how it is there.

I'm reading the file in Notepad++, it would be much easier to find data if I had its line number.

Is it possible for FFCM/Flat File Source to add the line number to the list of columns, so I can save it in the table?

Comment: I don't think it can be done directly. However you could import to a staging table with all char-based columns and an additional int column with identity defined. That way you could identity all the values that don't parse and look them up in the file. I'm not completely sure that the rows in the file will be loaded sequentially though. However, I think that the value itself should be enough to identify the offending row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jamesn/archive/2008/02/13/60509.aspx

It's not a CCFM or a Flat File Source, but it works pretty fine and it's elegant.